# Цикличная ошибка "shader program is not linked" при использовании PyQt

Tags: python, qt, opengl, pyqt

Разрабатываю программу на Python 2.7 и QML. Программа работоспособна на win10 x64 c использованием встроенной видеокарты (HD Graphics 630), но при этом абсолютно не работоспособна на win10 x64 c использованием видеоадаптера NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti.

Выдаёт цикличную ошибку:

```
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( qt_Matrix ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed:
```

Не могу понять в чём собственно говоря дело?

PyQt,PyOpenGL, Qt, qtpy - установлены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была вызвана удалённым подключением с использованием протокола RDP к вычислительной машине на которой запускался интерфейс QML.